# How to configure logging to file for Apache Pulsar in standalone mode?

Tags: logging, log4j, apache-pulsar, pulsar

I want to configure Apache Pulsar to log output to file when in standalone mode.

I am running Pulsar in standalone mode from a `systemd` service, with an exec command like this:

```sh
/var/lib/apache-pulsar/bin/pulsar standalone
```

Now the Pulsar log configuration is documented [here](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.2/reference-configuration/#log4j), and specifies that you can use configuration properties like `pulsar.root.logger` to configure logging through Log4J.

However what is not clear is *where* do you define these log-related properties? In which configuration file do they go?

Or should you make changes in `log4j2.yaml` directly? This is not covered in the documentation. Changing e.g. `pulsar.routing.appender.default` to `RollingFile` does not seem to have an effect.

Describing the complete steps of enabling logging to file in standalone mode would be very helpful.